# How to compress images without using imageMagick or GD?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell how to compress the uploaded images with PHP but without using the imageMagick and GD?

Please also tell how to resize the images too.

Comment: Does it need to remain as an image or could it be an archive? You could just gzip it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use command line tools via `exec` like `optipng` , `Jpegtran` etc 
`

```
exec("optipng largefie.png -out compressed.png");
```